# mongodb search by multiple tags

Tags: mongodb

I am reading the mongoDB manual for searching by tags (elements in arrays); here is the page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/

But, how do I search while using multiple keyworks? Can an array be used like this?

single keyword:

```
db.volumes.findOne( { topics : "voyage" }, { title: 1 } )
```

many keywords:

db.volumes.findOne( { topics : ['voyage', 'nautical'] }, { title: 1 } )

Comment: You will need to use the $in operator: `db.volumes.findOne( { topics : {$in: ['voyage', 'nautical']} }, { title: 1 } )`

Comment: great... if you can put it as an answer I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the $in ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/ ) operator here to list a range of words to use to search the tags array by:

```
db.volumes.findOne( { topics : {$in: ['voyage', 'nautical']} }, { title: 1 } )
```

Comment: Does this approach offer good performance when the collection grows?

Comment: @Trace so long as the field is properly indexed yes, $in is inclusive which is very fast, it wouldn't  scale well if you was using a $nin